# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: number | undefined) => number | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, setstate

I am using material ui's select component to save the selected value in a variable:

```ts
const [ratio, setRatio] = useState<number>();
...
const handleChangeRatio = (e: React.ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: unknown; }>) => {
    //const value = typeof e.target.value === "number" ? e.target.value : "";
    setRatio(e.target.value);
};
...
    <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-filled"
        value={splittingMethod}
        onChange={(e)=>handleChangeRatio(e)}
    >
        <MenuItem value={0}>
            0
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={0.1}>0.1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={0.2}>0.2</MenuItem>
    </Select>
```

However, I get this error while setting the state inside the handleChange function, how can I fix this?

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number | undefined>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: number | undefined) => number | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React's `useState<number>()` returns a tuple of values with types: `ratio: number | undefined`, `setRatio: SeStateAction<number | undefined>`. While you're trying to feed to `setRatio` value of type `unknown`.

The easiest way is to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type `unknown` to `number`:

```ts
const handleChangeRatio = (e: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    if (typeof e.target.value === 'number') setRatio(e.target.value)
};
```

or with better runtime safety:

```ts
const handleChangeRatio = (e: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    const value = Number(e.target.value)
    if (!isNaN(value)) setRatio(value)
};
```

Comment: this seems to work fine on the front-end but gives an error ```VM334:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0``` on the console

Comment: I believe that's not relevant to the event handler. `Unexpected token ... in JSON` is a common problem when one tries to parse `text` response/data as a JSON.